# How to import Homebrew SDL2_image with CMake (Mac M1)

Tags: c, macos, cmake, apple-silicon, sdl-image

I installed SDL2_image with home-brew (so installed at */opt/homebrew/Cellar/*) but I can't make CMake detecting it...

I tried installing the Framework version, but it seems to not be compatible with the ARM ship...

I Also tried to add */opt/homebrew/Cellar/* to *PATH* variable.

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Program C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(MemoryCheck REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MEMORY_CHECK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${MEMORY_CHECK_LIB_DIRS})

add_executable(Program main.c)
target_link_libraries(Program ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${MEMORY_CHECK_LIBRARIES})
```

*cmake/FindSDL2_image.cmake*

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License. See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.

#.rst:
# FindSDL2_image
# -------------
#
# Locate SDL2_image library
#
# This module defines:
#
# ::
#
# SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS, where to find the headers
# SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND, if false, do not try to link against
# SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_STRING - human-readable string containing the
# version of SDL2_image
#
#
#
# For backward compatibility the following variables are also set:
#
# ::
#
# SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARY (same value as SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES)
# SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR (same value as SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
# SDL2IMAGE_FOUND (same value as SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND)
#
#
#
# $SDLDIR is an environment variable that would correspond to the
# ./configure --prefix=$SDLDIR used in building SDL.
#
# Created by Eric Wing. This was influenced by the FindSDL.cmake
# module, but with modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).

if(NOT SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR AND SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR} CACHE PATH "directory cache entry initialized from old variable name")
endif()
find_path(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR SDL_image.h
        HINTS
        ENV SDL2IMAGEDIR
        ENV SDL2DIR
        ${SDL2_DIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES SDL2
        # path suffixes to search inside ENV{SDL2DIR}
        include/SDL2 include
        )

if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(VC_LIB_PATH_SUFFIX lib/x64)
else()
    set(VC_LIB_PATH_SUFFIX lib/x86)
endif()

if(NOT SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY AND SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARY)
    set(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARY} CACHE FILEPATH "file cache entry initialized from old variable name")
endif()
find_library(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY
        NAMES SDL2_image
        HINTS
        ENV SDL2IMAGEDIR
        ENV SDL2DIR
        ${SDL2_DIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib ${VC_LIB_PATH_SUFFIX}
        )

if(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR AND EXISTS "${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}/SDL2_image.h")
    file(STRINGS "${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}/SDL2_image.h" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR_LINE REGEX "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_MAJOR_VERSION[ \t]+[0-9]+$")
    file(STRINGS "${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}/SDL2_image.h" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR_LINE REGEX "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_MINOR_VERSION[ \t]+[0-9]+$")
    file(STRINGS "${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}/SDL2_image.h" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH_LINE REGEX "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_PATCHLEVEL[ \t]+[0-9]+$")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_MAJOR_VERSION[ \t]+([0-9]+)$" "\\1" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR_LINE}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_MINOR_VERSION[ \t]+([0-9]+)$" "\\1" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR_LINE}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^#define[ \t]+SDL2_IMAGE_PATCHLEVEL[ \t]+([0-9]+)$" "\\1" SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH_LINE}")
    set(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_STRING ${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH})
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR_LINE)
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR_LINE)
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH_LINE)
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MAJOR)
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_MINOR)
    unset(SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_PATCH)
endif()

set(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY})
set(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2_image
        REQUIRED_VARS SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS
        VERSION_VAR SDL2_IMAGE_VERSION_STRING)

# for backward compatibility
set(SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARY ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
set(SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SDL2IMAGE_FOUND ${SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND})

mark_as_advanced(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on and M1 mac but used brew to install SDL2_image also. The following seemed to help me:

```
find_path(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR SDL_image.h
  HINTS
    ENV SDL2IMAGEDIR
    ENV SDL2DIR
    ${SDL2_DIR}
    "/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.0.5"
  PATH_SUFFIXES SDL2
                # path suffixes to search inside ENV{SDL2DIR}
                include/SDL2 include
)
```

Where the key line is "/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.0.5". This may be different for you.